# Drag and Drop not working when loaded using SWFLoader?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript-2

I am currently loading an AS2 SWF in flex using SWFLoader, and the loaded AS2 SWF has drag and drop activity in it. When I run the AS2 swf in standalone player, the drag and drop works fine, but when I loaded it in flex using SWFLoader, the drag and drop doesn't work. Any help on this would be great, thanks.

[Flex Code](http://pastebin.com/uaWRdVyS) and [AS2 FLA](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/107176/slide_8.fla)

Comment: As far as I know, AS2 and AS3 bytecode is executed in a separate VM. I'm surprised this even works. I suppose some of the bytecode is still similar.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I dealt with loading as2 content into flex, what I did was re-implement drag and drop on the swfloader in as3 like so :

```
var swfLoader:Loader = new Loader();
swfLoader.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onMouseDown);


public function onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,onDrag);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,finishDrag);
}

public function onDrag(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    swfLoader.x = stage.mouseX;
    swfLoader.y = stage.mouseY;
}

public function finishDrag(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,onDrag);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,finishDrag);
}
```

Comment: Hey Baris, thanks for the post, will try out and post the outcome. Thanks again.

Comment: I did try what you suggested but doesn't seem to work. Firstly I get this error "1024: Overriding a function that is not marked for override." at the line where stopDrag is declared, and if I rename the function and compile, it gets compiled but not able to do drag & drop.

Comment: Ahh stopDrag is an existing function of sprite so just rename it to something else.